# WPF User Control - Check property value before rendering?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I've got a user control that contains a tree view.  The control has two styles for the treeview items: the "DefaultStyle" that shows an image and text, and the "CheckboxStyle" that displays a checkbox before the image.

To control which style is used, the user control has a boolean property called "CheckboxStyle".  When set to True, the "CheckboxStyle" style is applied to the TreeviewItem objects.

When set to "True" through XAML, the CheckBoxStyle property has no effect because the control has already rendered itself with the default style (CheckboxStyle == False).  When set through code outside of the control, it also has no effect for the same reason.  However, when set explicitly *inside* the constructor for the control or the property, it works.

What's the best way to go about enforcing the effect of the boolean CheckboxStyle property from XAML, or from code outside of the control?

Comment: Please delete all your code and see [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN to understand the proper way to do what you're trying to do in WPF. From your description it seems like you don't really need a `TreeViewItem` style, but rather a simple `DataTemplate`.

Comment: The data templates are defined in the styles themselves.  Additionally, the reason that this is a user control is that it is used in several places around the application.

Comment: @HighCore: Is right. You shouldn't be styling TreeViewItems based on a property on your Control. You should be creating a DataTemplate for a ViewModel. Above can be done in less than 10 lines of code using a normal WPF TreeView.